# Android - start new activity that does not extend Activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, processing

I am trying to run a Processing class from my MainActivity. I believe that I am running my intent properly but I get the error:

```
12-17 22:53:44.221: E/AndroidRuntime(1904): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-17 22:53:44.221: E/AndroidRuntime(1904): Process: bard.edu.focus2, PID: 1904
12-17 22:53:44.221: E/AndroidRuntime(1904): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {bard.edu.focus2/bard.edu.focus2.ProcessingInterface}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
12-17 22:53:44.221: E/AndroidRuntime(1904):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1628)
12-17 22:53:44.221: E/AndroidRuntime(1904):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
12-17 22:53:44.221: E/AndroidRuntime(1904):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3424)
```

And the class is declared in my manifest:

```
<activity
        android:name="edu.bard.focus2.ProcessingInterface" 
        android:parentActivityName="edu.bard.focus2.MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>        
</activity>
```

Here is my intent:

```
runFocus = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonProcessing);
    runFocus.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ProcessingInterface.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent,START_PROCESSING);
        }
     }
```

The thing is my processing class (which functions properly on its own) extends PApplet and not Activity which could be at the origin of the error.
If I'm right, what can I do to fix it?
If not, any suggestion?

Thanks !

Comment: As in log use `bard.edu.focus2.ProcessingInterface` instead of `edu.bard.focus2.ProcessingInterface` to declare activity in Manifest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have given the wrong package name according to your log.

Change:

```
<activity
        android:name="edu.bard.focus2.ProcessingInterface" 
        android:parentActivityName="edu.bard.focus2.MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>        
    </activity>
```

to

```
<activity
        android:name="bard.edu.focus2.ProcessingInterface" 
        android:parentActivityName="bard.edu.focus2.MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>        
    </activity>
```

or,if your main packcage name is bard.edu.focus2 then you can simply write:

```
 <activity
            android:name=".ProcessingInterface"
            >
        </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got to extend `Activity`, so far as I know, otherwise it's not going to work -- no `Context`, no . . . . well, many, many things. Try the approach [in this tutorial instead](http://blog.blprnt.com/blog/blprnt/processing-android-mobile-app-development-made-very-easy). It walks you through using a special Android-enabled Processing build.

Comment: Thanks for the tip ! I was originally using this approach, by just launching the processing code as the mainActivity. But then I lack a User interface in which I can load an Image from my phone and get input from the User...

Comment: There are some additional libraries for user prompts to load images, etc.: http://pif.github.io/android-select-file/. But you're right, the docs make it clear there is limited mixing allowed of Android UI elements. I love Processing too, but gave up on it when trying to get a sketch running as Android wallpaper.

Answer (score 0):

you havn't add you newly created Activity in your Manifest file.
Add following code in your manifest file before  tag

```
 <activity android:name=".newclassname" >
        </activity>
```

or

```
  <activity android:name="packagename.newclassname" >
            </activity>
```

Comment: I have, ProcessingInterface is my new class. Above it I have my mainActivity declared, but I didn't included it in my code here

Comment: <activity android:name=".ProcessingInterface" >
        </activity> so include like this.